# Receiving Check via Mail for goods being sold

Tags: check, online-payment, sba

I recently open an online shop and I was just wondering about the different payment methods that are considered to be the safest on a business standpoint.

Today I received one customer interested in purchasing one of my goods, she declared to pay me with a "commercial check" and send it through mail (Im in Puerto Rico, customer is in Florida). Is it normal for a payment to be this way, client claims to have no paypal account.

Check is being mailed to me personally and is being "payed" to me personally.

Should I be wary of anything? Is this normal for online businesses?

Any suggestions on payment methods that can protect my business? I was thinking on paypal and an invoice order.

Please discuss.

Mr. A.O.C.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about running a business.

Comment: We do allow questions regarding _small_ businesses, single-owner LLCs and the like on this site, and so I don't think this is as off-topic as four people have voted. That being said, the main issue is that the check is being made payable to Mr AOC personally instead of to his online business. It raises all kinds of alarm bells in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a check, and I am assuming that it's drawn on a US bank, you will want to hold off on shipping until you are sure the check has cleared.

Since you are in PR it will depend on your bank there.  If they are a branch of a US bank it shouldn't take more than a few days.  Otherwise, if it's a local PR bank it make take up to 2 weeks.

So how you handle this is up to you and the amount of risk you are willing to take.